# Timeout when doing a PUT in Amazon S3 (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature

I am trying to do a PUT request in Amazon S3 using the Signature V4. I use the 100-continue option.

```
PUT /<bucket_name>/img.jpg 
Host: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXXPUBLIC_KEY/20141217/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;expect;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=b8f0ab15e2395176ed46a26e667528a5ff1e2a44b45e7450353e63416b22e204
x-amz-date: 20141217T151702Z
x-amz-content-sha256:0536ca77167cfef1dff0822dbf35441d595bb42bf21ccc8e78d4ba52e6192a7e
content-type:image/jpeg
content-length:169029
expect:100-continue
```

First it runs fine getting a http code 100. Then I get a 400 Bad Request error because of a Timeout issue. However, if I use the AWS cli to do the same request, everything runs OK.

Any idea of what happens?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the `Content-Length:` header you should be sending with your request?

Comment: @Michael, thanks. I forgot writing the content-length header. However the issue persists.

Comment: How long do you have to wait after sending the data until you see the timeout occur?  Have you confirmed that the content-length is correctly counted (body only) and that you are successfully writing that many bytes? Is there a reason your path isn't followed by `HTTP/1.1`? What happens if you don't use expect: 100-continue?